# Adding together sum of salary with yearly pay increase in one query - SQL PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have a basic table detailing members of staff and yearly salary.

I want to calculate the total cost to the business for 3 years of salary, but with a yearly pay rise of 3%, starting with a pay rise today and ending 3 years from now.

So the method should be `(SUM of SALARY * 1.03) + (THAT TOTAL * 1.03) + (THIRD TOTAL * 1.03) = 3` year cost with yearly pay rises included.

I have attempted the following (y stands for year):

```
SELECT ((SUM("salary")  * 1.03 AS "y2") + ("y2" * 1.03 AS "y3"), + ("y3" * 1.03)) AS "totalCost" 
FROM public."groundStaff";
```

With the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT ((SUM("salary")  * 1.05 AS "s2") + ("s2" * 1.05 AS "s...
                                       ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 32
```

I have also tried moving the brackets around but to no avail.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select sum(salary) as year_0,
       sum(salary) * 1.03 as year_1,
       sum(salary) * 1.03 * 1.03 as year_2,
       sum(salary) * 1.03 * 1.03 * 1.03 as year_3
from public."groundStaff";
```

Or, if you want a lot of  years, and you can put them on separate rows:

```
select gs.y,
       sum(salary) * power(1.03, gs.y) as salary
from public."groundStaff" cross join
     generate_series(0, 3) as gs(y)
group by gs.y    
order by gs.y;
```

Comment: Awesome answers both! Second answer requires 'group by'. Thank you!